# What is the difference between issuing company and holding company in a convertible bond

Tags: canada, etf, bonds, arbitrage

I am researching convertible bonds in Canada. While looking at the index etf that tracks convertible bonds, [CVD](https://www.blackrock.com/ca/individual/en-ca/products/239435/ishares-convertible-bond-index-etf?locale=en_CA&siteEntryPassthrough=true)

What I don't understand is how come the list of Top 10 issuers is different from teh list of Top 10 Holdings?

The issuing company should be same in which the company has the holding, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top 10 holdings is related to the ETF in question, ranked according to the weight of holdings in each of the issuer.

Top 10 issuers primarily means the top 10 among the holdings(of the ETF), who have issued the highest number of convertible bonds(in total not only new), they can issue new bonds after the ETF has bought it's current holdings or they might have issued bonds before the ETF bought it's current holdings.